# Convert a 2-D vector into a 4-D vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Is it possible to convert a 2-D vector into a 4-D vector in matlab ?

I could create 2-D vectors like for example:

```
A = [[1 2];[3 4]] -->(code segment_1)
```

and 4-D vectors like

```
A = ones(2,3,4,8)  -->(code segment_2)
```

Is it possible to create a 4-D vector like how we could create the 2-D vector using code_segment_1? (Let me be more clear, `A=[[[1 2],[3 4]],[[5 6],[7 8]],[[9 10],[11 12]]]` is creating a 1x12 matrix instead)

Also I saw we use `reshape` function to convert a k-Dimensional matrix into l-Dimensional matrix where k > l. This is basically down scaling but can we upscale the dimensions?

Comment: You need to use the `A(:,:,:,k)` notation or reshape a `1D` or `2D` version of the input into `4D`.

Comment: `reshape` can also "upscale". Just feed it with the appropriate dimensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `reshape` your 2D *matrix* into a 4D array, as long as you do not change the number of elements:

```
 oneD = 1:12; %// creare 1D vector
 twoD = reshape( oneD, [6 2] ); %// reshape into a 2D matrix
 threeD = reshape( oneD, [2 3 2] ); %// now you have a 3D array
 fourD = reshape( oneD, [1 2 3 2] ); %// 4D with a leading singleton dimension
```

From your question it seems like you have some experience with numpy. Matlab does not have a direct command-line creation of n-d arrays for `n`>2, but it is straight-forward to `reshape` any 2D or 3D array into higher-dimensional one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me solve my silly doubt .. Also I had used numpy module when I was implementing a toy page ranker ..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *directly* create the 4D array (without `reshape`) you need to use a slightly more cumbersome syntax, with the [`cat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function:

```
A = cat(4, cat(3, [1 2],[3 4]), cat(3, [5 6],[7 8]), cat(3, [9 10],[11 12]));
```